# Can the firebase emulator test cloud functions that use the node.js admin SDK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm working on a legacy app that uses cloud functions. Cloud functions and firebase as a whole are new to me. ATM, we have to deploy to a real and shared environment to test functionality. This is risky, because we often break our shared environment to test out certain functionality. I'm trying figure out a way to test locally first.

To me, it seems like the [firebase emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) should be the solution. But, there's a matrix on there that says, "n/a" for "Node.js Admin SDK," and our cloud functions are importing that dependency and are written in node.

[image]

What does "n/a" mean in this context? Does it mean, "it doesn't make sense to emulate that so it's non-applicable," or does it mean, "you can't emulate this at this time, so you won't be able to test cloud functions locally if they use this SDK," or something else entirely?

Comment: Hi Daniel, for my own personal experience, you can use the Admin SDK and test your functions. I run Emulator Suite by typing `firebase emulators:start`, all services that I use and are supported by this Suite runs locally. There may be some services that you use and are not supported by Emulators. In those cases the Admin SDK will affect your Firebase application.

Comment: [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin#:~:text=lets%20you%20interact%20with%20firebase%20from%20privileged%20environments) is to access Firebase from privileged environments, but has nothing to do with Cloud Functions. Thus, I believe "n/a" stands for "non applicable" as it doesn't makes sense to emulate it. However, you could still use it with no further issues as @Lucas pointed out within a Cloud Function inside the emulator, as [shown in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#add-the-addmessage-function)